# CoreText Page view example (CTPageViewer)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, core-text, wwdc

I was watching "Advance Text Handling for iPhone OS" video from WWDC. I really like the demo and want to play with it, but once i download source code from WWDC and try to look for the example. I could not find it. Is there any one who knows from where i can download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the iOS Reference Library under the name CoreTextPageViewer here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: its not exactly the same but we can make that WWDC project using this code :). So Thank you so much for sharing this link

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645). You'll need a developer account to access it.

Comment: I already try that :) But this does not contain CoreText code sample